# Windows Server 2008 r2 Remote Desktop Services role

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop-services

I've installed the Remote Desktop Services role on a 2008 r2 server, but I want to remove it. Basically it was done in anticipation of our company getting the licenses, but they've decided not to now.

My question is: If I remove the role and reboot, will we still be able to establish RDP connections to the server as before?

I'm talking about the two connections you are allowed without licensing - does this need reconfiguring? I can't seem to find any clear answer online, and I don't want to render the server inaccessible as it's hosted off site. Anybody done this before?

Thanks.

Comment: `If I remove the role and reboot, will we still be able to establish RDP connections to the server as before? I'm talking about the two connections you are allowed without licensing` - Yes. `does this need reconfiguring?` -No.

Answer (score 0):

As joeqwerty said in his comment, it appears to work fine. The server took it's sweet time coming back up, but I can still log in remotely.